# Swift var not changing

Tags: swift

First post, did try to search for an answer before writing, but none of the posts gave me the answer, so I'm asking. 
I bet it's something simple, that I just can't see.

I have a var for score. I want to add 1 to it every time collision takes place.
Here's how it's written

```
var score:Int = 0
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
var scoreOnScreen = SKLabelNode(text:"(\score)")
```

then, in the collide function, after bullet and the enemy are removed

```
func bulletDidCollideWithEnemy(bullet: SKSpriteNode, enemyOne: SKSpriteNode) {
  score++
  bullet.removeFromParent() 
  enemyOne.removeFromParent() 
}
```

But on the screen, it's still 0.

Why?

Comment: Is your collide function getting called?

Comment: You should show the collide function code

Comment: Yes. When it does, it removeFromParent() stuff that collides. And that is where i wrote score++

    func bulletDidCollideWithEnemy(bullet: SKSpriteNode, enemyOne: SKSpriteNode) {

        score++

        bullet.removeFromParent()
        enemyOne.removeFromParent()
    }

Comment: It's not showing any errors, it just seems irrational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating your `score` on UI.You are just udating variable `score`.Write code to update `scoreOnScreen` in `bulletDidCollideWithEnemy`

```
func bulletDidCollideWithEnemy(bullet: SKSpriteNode, enemyOne: SKSpriteNode) {
  score++
  scoreOnScreen.text = "\(score)"
  bullet.removeFromParent() 
  enemyOne.removeFromParent() 
}
```